# Why I have AttributeError? I'm learning Kivy, but cmd print: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'

Tags: python-3.7

I'm learning Kivy and when I run file in cmd, cmd print: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'

Where Is problem??

Code(little piece):
main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
)
from kivy.vector import Vector

class PongBall(Widget):

class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(4, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))
```

pong.kv(piece with ball's function):

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<PongBall>:
   size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongGame>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height


full code:
main.py: 
https://pastebin.com/12XtvXKP
pong.kv:
https://pastebin.com/5Ag6UrB0
```

Comment: IIUC the error happen at `self.ball.center = self.center`? so, have you defined `center` attribute of `self.ball`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, runs fine in my computer. Is this entirely kivy example about Pong Game?